# Solve integral equation $(f(x))^{2}=2 \int_{0}^{x} f(t) \sqrt{1-t^{2}} \mathrm{~d} t, \quad x \in[0,1]$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

The aim is to solve this integration $$(f(x))^{2}=2 \int_{0}^{x} f(t) \sqrt{1-t^{2}} \mathrm{~d} t, \quad x \in[0,1]$$
I have found that $\cos ( \arcsin(x))=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $\sin (2 \arcsin(x))=2x\sqrt{1-x^2}$
And I have tried the following, but according to solution it should have 2 solutions, so I don't know if I have done this correctly so far
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \frac{d}{d x} \int_{0}^{\varphi(x)} g(t) d t=\varphi(x)g(\varphi(x)) \\
2 f(x) f^{\prime}(x) &=2 f(x) \sqrt{1-x^{2}} \\
2 y y^{\prime} &=2 y\sqrt{1-x^{2}} \\
\frac{d y}{d x} &=\sqrt{1-x^{2}} \\
\int d y &=\int \sqrt{1-x^{2}} d x \\
y+c_{1} &=\int \sqrt{1-\sin ^{2} t  }  \cos t dt\\
&=\int \cos ^{2}t d t \\
y &=\frac{1}{2} \arcsin x+\frac{1}{4} \sin (2 \arcsin (x)) +C\\
y &=\frac{1}{2} \arcsin x+\frac{1}{4} 2 x \sqrt{1-x^{2}}+C
\end{aligned}
$$

I would really appreciate your comments!

Comment: This looks correct, but you should also see that before cancelling the $f(x)$ that $f(x)=0$ is a separate solution.

Comment: For the below integral try u-substitution.

Comment: At the stage where you have $2yy'=2y\sqrt{1-x^2},$ notice that $y=0$ is a solution. So the solutions are $f(x)=0$ and the solution you found **for some fixed C.** You should go and check which values of $C$ makes the equation true. Alternatively, when you get to $y'=\sqrt{1-x^2},$ you can use definite integration instead. Notice that $$\int_0^xy'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^x\sqrt{1-t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t=y(x)-y(0)$$ with $x\in[0,1].$ Hence $$\int_0^x\sqrt{1-t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^{\arcsin(x)}\cos(t)^2\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac12[\arcsin(x)+x\sqrt{1-x^2}].$$ From here, you can try to maximize the RHS.

Comment: After doing the substitution into the original equation to find the allowed values of $C=y(0)=f(0),$ I found that $f(0)^2=\frac18.$

Answer (score 1):

At the stage where you have $2yy′=2y\sqrt{1−x^2},$ notice that $y=0$ is a solution. So the solutions are $f(x)=0$ and the solution you found **for some fixed C.** You should go and check which values of C makes the equation true. After doing the substitution into the original equation to find the allowed values of $C=y(0)=f(0),$ I found that $f(0)^2=\frac18.$ Hence, you actually have three solutions on $[0,1],$ but whoever assigned you the exercise may omit the trivial $f(x)=0.$